# Regarding doing research on a main method()

Tags: java

i was doing an interesting Research today in my below code see how many ways we can express the public static void

```
 //public static void main (String args[])correct
    //public static void main (String []args)//correct
    //public static void main(String...args)//correct
    //public static void main(String... args)//correct
    public static void main(String[]... args)   //correct 
    static  public  void main (String args[])
```

Please advise is there any other way too.

Comment: @Thoms , This was a sort of research man..!1

Comment: @Alnitak research does not always be successful dude..!!

Comment: @user1351820: there's a requirement in the [faq] for questions to be "practical". This isn't, trying to find twisted main signatures that work serves absolutely no practical purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` method must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`; from [JLS 12.1.4](http://%20docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> ```
>   public static void main(String[] args)
>
>
>   public static void main(String... args)
> ```

Some JVM implementations in the past have not required a publicly accessible `main` method. On occasion this has been used to add private testing methods into APIs.

While the method modifiers `public` and `static` can be in any order ([JLS 8.4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3)), they must all come before the return type ([JLS 8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4)), so any combination such as `void static` is illegal.